# Find keys in dictionary with values that intersect with list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to write a function that finds all different people who have at least one of the given hobbies. The function returns a set of these names. I thought it would be logical to turn the string into a dictionary, and then compare dictionary values with what is in hobbies. I got the following:

```
def find_people_with_hobbies(data: str, hobbies: list) -> set:
    new_dict = create_dictionary(data) # creates a dictionary in the form {name1: [hobby1, hobby2, ...], name2: [...]}
    return set([k for k, v in new_dict.items() if v == hobbies])
```

So, given `data="John:running\nMary:running\nJohn:dancing\nJack:dancing\nJack:painting\nSmith:painting"` and `hobbies=["running", "dancing"]`, the result should be `{"John", "Mary", "Jack"}`. In my case, it only finds Jack. How can this be improved/fixed?

Comment: `v==hobbies` means that ALL the hobbies must appear. You should use `v in hobbies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the comparison between `v` and `hobbies`, i.e. the snippet `v == hobbies`. In your example, `find_people_with_hobbies` only returns `"Jack"` because Jack has *exactly* the hobbies in `hobbies`.

You should rather take the intersection of `v` and `hobbies` and check that it is not empty. You can do that with sets:

```py
def find_people_with_hobbies(data: str, hobbies: list) -> set:
    new_dict = create_dictionary(data) # creates a dictionary in the form {name1: [hobby1, hobby2, ...], name2: [...]}
    return set([k for k, v in new_dict.items() if set(v).intersection(hobbies)])
```

In addition, you could have `create_dictionary` create a dictionary with sets as values. That way you would not have to construct a set, `set(v)`, and could just do `v.intersection(hobbies)`. A set makes sense after all, since each hobby cannot be present more than once.